# Не могу придумать квантификатор

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть HTML страница, нужно вытащить начало и конец строки таблицы () относительно ключевого слова. Как завершить парсинг кода понятно, а вот как найти ближайшее значение слева и начать с него -- нет. Т.к. начинает поиск с первого найденного случая.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
/<tr\b(?:(?!<tr\b).)+Federal Funds Rate.*?<\/tr>/gs
```

Эта часть

```
(?:(?!<tr\b).)+
```

каждый раз, прежде чем захватить символ идет просмотр вперед на отсутствие `<tr` + границы слова.

P.S. Делает много шагов в процессе поиска. Эффективнее разбить строку по `Federal Funds Rate`, после этого в получившихся частях искать первый `</tr>` и последний `<tr\b`.